# How to restrict user not to select future date from calender view in android

Tags: android

I need to restrict the user from selecting future date from the calender view. It can be either error message or any other method that can help when the future date is selected.
Please feel free to teach me.

```
CV = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView1);
CV.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            cvSTR = dayOfMonth+" : "+(month+1)+" : "+year;
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Selected Date is\n\n"+cvSTR, 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            MyDay = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
            MyMonth = String.valueOf(month+1);
            MyYear = String.valueOf(year);
        }
        });
```

Comment: How does your calendar view look like now?

Comment: i updated my post, have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this:

```
Date maxDate = new Date(); //set your max date here
CV.setMaxDate(maxDate.getTime());
```

Comment: you mean this view? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html
have you tried using setMaxDate(long) ? the description says its also available

Answer (score 0):

Get the `DatePicker` used in your `DatePickerDialog` with the `getDatePicker()` method and use the `setDate(Long millis)`  method.

Pass to it the maximum date (in milliseconds from Epoch) you have to set.

So you can do something like

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());

CV = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView1);
CV.setMaxDate(d.getTime());
```

Comment: thank for reply,
but i looking for the solution on calender view not date picker

Comment: same method applies to CalendarView too

Comment: p.getCalenderView(); ??
what is that?
can you refer to the code i post and post a exactly correct way to do it?
please...